# Arithmetic temporaries in tex

Tags: arithmetic

Can i call macros something like this

```
\StrMid{\mystring}{\X}{\X+2}\par
```

So, i would like to have running window of length 3. And for this end i would like to be able to use temporary unnamed local variable `\X+2` as i can in C++.

Comment: Sorry, but it's very unclear what your aim is.

Comment: @egreg Op wishes, given a string, to be able to extract and display a substring (a *window* into the string). This substring should be specified by its start index and length, as opposed to start/end indices, using the `\StrMid` command from `xstring` package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\numexpr\X+2` in order to evaluate the number of the end-'index' here.

Of course `\numexpr\foo+\foobar` will be an even more flexible solution.

Since `\StrMid` is not expandable the usability of `\StrMid` depends on the real design.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}


\begin{document}
\def\foo{10}
\def\foobar{14}
\def\mystring{And now for something completely different}
\StrMid{\mystring}{\foo}{\numexpr\foo+\foobar}


\end{document}
```

This yields `or something c` here.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: ;-)  You should look for many other answers of mine having MP references -- you will get a lot of upvotes to be done then :D

Comment: It's not meant to be taken literally.  [Obviously it refers to any manufacturers of dairy products.]

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: What a pity/shame :D

Answer (score 4):

A fully expandable function, with the help of `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringwindow}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_map_function:fN { \tl_range:onn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } } \use:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_function:nN { f }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_range:nnn { o }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand\mystring{Andnowforsomethingcompletelydifferent}
\newcommand{\foo}{4}

\stringwindow{\mystring}{\foo}{\foo+2}

\edef\now{\stringwindow{\mystring}{\foo}{\foo+2}}
\texttt{\meaning\now}

\end{document}
```

The second and third argument of `\stringwindow` can be any integer denotation, that is, also counter registers, such as `\value{chapter}`, besides macros that expand to numbers.

Note: spaces are not preserved. A slower routine would be needed for this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Note that the macro `\StrMid` is fully expandable. All three arguments of `\StrMid` may consist of (or contain) macros; the only requirement is that the args evaluate to either a string (the first arg) or integers (the second and third arg). And, the result of `\StrMid` may be assigned to a new macro.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luastring" macro
\newcommand\StrMid[3]{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.sub(\luastring{#1},#2,#3))}}

\newcommand\mystring{Andnowforsomethingcompletelydifferent}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\foo{2+2} % something that evaluates to an integer in Lua 

\StrMid{\mystring}{\foo}{\foo+2} % returns "now"

% assign result of \StrMid to a LaTeX macro:
\newcommand\bbar{\StrMid{\mystring}{\foo+19}{\foo+21}}
\bbar % returns "let"
\end{document}
```